# "os x" + octave + Miscellaneous Package: install errors

Tags: installation, package, octave

Trying to install the `Miscellaneous` Package into `Octave`, I get this string of errors:

> octave-3.2.3:17> pkg install miscellaneous-1.0.9.tar.gz configure:
>   error: in
>   /var/folders/0o/0ox7a-rlFVGd8pZnuF96sE+++TM/-Tmp-/oct-zTlMUh/miscellaneous-1.0.9/src:
>   configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables See
>   config.log for more details. the configure script returned the
>   following error: checking for gcc... gcc checking for C compiler
>   default output file name...  error: called from `pkg>configure_make
>   in file
>   /Applications/Octave.app/Contents/Resources/share/octave/3.2.3/m/pkg/pkg.m
>   near line 1240, column 2 error: called from: error:
>   /Applications/Octave.app/Contents/Resources/share/octave/3.2.3/m/pkg/pkg.m
>   at line 714, column 5 error:
>   /Applications/Octave.app/Contents/Resources/share/octave/3.2.3/m/pkg/pkg.m
>   at line 287, column 7

What is this trying to tell me? Where should I go?

Mike Briggs

Comment: The important part seems to be “error: C compiler cannot create executables”. **Do you do have a compiler installed?** It comes with the developer tools (along with Xcode). Look for it on your install DVD or download from Apple (you will probably need to regerister for a free Apple Developer Connection account to download).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's related but if you are using the prepackaged Octave.app version 3.2.3 you need to reconfigure the file Octave.app/Contents/Resources/bin/mkoctfile-3.2.3 so that it will build installed packages in 32bit instead of 64bit...

> The solution is to add the following snippet

```
CFLAGS="-m32 ${CFLAGS}" 
FFLAGS="-m32 ${FFLAGS}" 
CPPFLAGS="-m32 ${CPPFLAGS}" 
CXXFLAGS="-m32 ${CXXFLAGS}"
LDFLAGS="-m32 ${LDFLAGS}"
```

> in the file Octave.app/Contents/Resources/bin/mkoctfile-3.2.3 just after the "set -e" line. The problem was that in Snow Leopard compilers try always to build in 64bit, while libraries shipped with Octave are 32 bit. The -m32 flag forces the compiler to build 32bit
>   programs. - Guido
>
> [Original Post](http://old.nabble.com/Problems-in-installing-Octave-General-package-td25894474.html#a25894474)

Comment: I apologize for taking so long to respond. Either the alerts did not make it to my inbox, or I just plain missed them. Ben and Chris, thank you for your responses. I will try the snippet after finals are over and report back. -- Mike Briggs